# Enabling I2S on Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 board

Tags: kernel, drivers, audio

I'd like to configure a Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 board for I2S communication as an I2S slave to an external codec. Currently, the board has some GPIOs that can be configured for I2S function. How can I do this configuration?

Also, I need to have the 820 is slave mode. Is there a way to modify the kernel to configure the device as I2S slave?